# LaTeX changes font converting eps to pdf

Tags: fonts, eps, epstopdf, embedding

I have the following figure made with Dia, a .eps file: 
[image]

When I include it in my .tex file...

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.8]{fig/complex.eps}
    \caption{......}
    \label{fig:figcomplex}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

The conversion is not going right even it seems so in TeXStudio terminal.

Comment: does the eps have the fonts embedded or are they just referenced by name? what happens if you use eps2pdf on the commandline to make pdf version, do you get warnings from ghostscript?

Comment: Was the ,eps file created on the same system?  The usual reason for "loss" of a font in a graphic is that this font is used only in graphics, and does not appear in the main text, and is then not recognized as being needed when the pdf file is created.  If the graphic was created on another system, the font may not even exist on the system on which the LaTeX job is processed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have the dia app and texstudio in the same machine, that's not the problem.

Comment: if you convert the eps to pdf and then view the pdf in a pdf viewer does it look right?

Comment: It does  not.  @DavidCarlisle

Comment: So whatever the problems latex is not involved as it just includes the PDF converted from the eps

Comment: As @David Carlisle wrote, fonts did not get embedded in PDF. Can you provide MWE and used EPS or PDF file?